# Python3 цикл for

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

```
from func import *
import pprint

data = Request('dfd')
pprint.pprint(data)
```

Python3. Функция возвращает список со вложенностью. Когда обрабатываю его циклом for то получаю только первые элементы списка. Подсказать где ошибаюсь.

data содержит:

```
{'Clouds': [{'decodeResult': 'broken clouds at 800 feet (250 meter)',
             'description': 'Clouds',
             'originalChunk': 'BKN008',
             'stringOffset': {'end': 33, 'start': 27}}],
 'Identifier': [{'decodeResult': 'Anapa Airport, Russian Federation.',
                 'description': 'Identifier',
                 'originalChunk': 'URKA',
                 'stringOffset': {'end': 4, 'start': 0}}],
 'Pressure': [{'decodeResult': 'QNH 1024 hPa (30.24 inHg)',
               'description': 'Pressure',
               'originalChunk': 'Q1024',
               'stringOffset': {'end': 45, 'start': 40}}],
 'Temperature': [{'decodeResult': 'Temperature 7ºC (45ºF), Dewpoint 6ºC (43ºF)',
                  'description': 'Temperature',
                  'originalChunk': '07/06',
                  'stringOffset': {'end': 39, 'start': 34}}],
 'Time Issued': [{'decodeResult': 'Issued on the 28th of the month at 05:30 '
                                  'UTC',
                  'description': 'Time Issued',
                  'originalChunk': '280530Z',
                  'stringOffset': {'end': 12, 'start': 5}}],
 'Visibility': [{'decodeResult': 'Visibility is 10km (6 statute miles) or more',
                 'description': 'Visibility',
                 'originalChunk': '9999',
                 'stringOffset': {'end': 26, 'start': 22}}],
 'Wind': [{'decodeResult': 'Winds from 90º (E) at 5 mps (10 knots)',
           'description': 'Wind',
           'originalChunk': '09005MPS',
           'stringOffset': {'end': 21, 'start': 13}}]}
```

нужно у каждого элемента получить параметр decodeResult.
например, Clouds - broken clouds at 800 feet (250 meter) и так далее
пишу так

```
for p in data:
    pprint.pprint(p)
```

но выходят только сами первые элементы

Comment: Это не список со вложенностью, а словарь. Чтобы при итерации получать не только ключи, но и значения, используйте метод словаря items: `for key, value in data.items(): print(key, value)`

Comment: вы совсем не знаете питон или настолько ленивы? хотя бы попытались

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value[0].get('decodeResult'))
```